# How to parameterize DataSet with group variable?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have 'external' table.

Inside each row of this table I need to show several tables associated with different DataSets.

But I have no idea how I can constrain these 'internal' DataSets with parameters of the group.

Is it possible?

**Update**

The next step may be to show subreport.;) The problem is that when nested DataSets have empty results subreport is not shown... even static content.

Here is a [nice post](https://coderwall.com/p/meqrng) hot to force subreport to appear.

The idea is simple. You need to add fake DataSet to subreport with query like:

```
select ' ' as Dummy
```

and use the result in visible textbox like that:

```
=First(Fields!DUMMY.Value, "DataSetToForceSubreportVisibility")
```

It works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with sub-reports.

1)  Create a report, which contains all the "internal" tables you want for each row of the "external" table.   Populate it with a dataset that has an ID parameter for which member of the outer group this is, so that all the internal tables will only be about a single group member.

2)  Create a main report for your external table.   This report contains a List control, and you populate it with a dataset that gets the members (IDs) of your outer group.

Inside each cell of the list is a subreport, which is the report you created in 1).  You pass to the ID parameter of the subreport the field containing the IDs you selected for the List control.